# rowspan and colspan in apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to create rowspan and colspan in apache poi.Can you tell  me how i  can accomplish something like this.I have tried using addMergedRegion method but that seem to be doing only colspan

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Month</td>
    <td colspan="2">Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>feb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your hint to `addMergedRegion` I suspect you are talking about the `Excel` parts of `apache poi`.

There it works for me using `Java` and `apache poi` version `3.17` as in the following example:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

public class CreateExcelMergedRegions {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 /*
 goal:
     +---------+---------+----------+
     |    A    |    B    |    C     |
 +---+------------------------------+
 | 1 |         |      Savings       |
 +---+ Month   |--------------------+
 | 2 |         | January | February |
 +---+---------+---------+----------+
 */

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(0,0,1,2); // row 1 col B and C
  sheet.addMergedRegion(mergedRegion);
  mergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(0,1,0,0); // row 1 and 2 col A 
  sheet.addMergedRegion(mergedRegion);

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0); // row 1
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0); // cell A1
  cell.setCellValue("Month");
  // set vertical alignment center
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, VerticalAlignment.CENTER); 

  cell = row.createCell(1); // cell B1
  cell.setCellValue("Savings");
  // set horizontal alignment center
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  row = sheet.createRow(1); // row 2
  cell = row.createCell(1); // cell B2
  cell.setCellValue("January");
  cell = row.createCell(2); // cell C2
  cell.setCellValue("February");

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelMergedRegions.xlsx");      
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelMergedRegions.xls");   
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
  }
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

I suspect you had missed the setting of alignment?